# Removing INDIRECT from dynamic column selection

Tags: excel

I have researched thoroughly before posting and still can't figure this out.

I currently have a file that uses an `INDIRECT` logic to gather information from one worksheet to a summary worksheet. The file works perfectly as is. But I'm trying to make it more efficient as right now calculating times are huge due to so much volatility.

In the data worksheet I have a lot of columns, each with a concept and an account number assigned to it.
So, for example:

> ```
>                 5014255   5324232     5566544        
> Name   Store    Salary     Taxes    Other Benefit     P1 Weight  P2 Weight
> John   Main     222222     50000       30000            0.4        0.6
> Jane   Annex    222224     50002       30004            0.3        0.7
> ```

Then in the summary page, I use a `SUMPRODUCT` to gather the information per store per account and separating by period, like this as:

> ```
> Store  Account     Concept           P1        P2
> Main   5014255   Salary            88888.8  133333.2
> Main   5324232   Taxes             20000.0   30000.0
> Main   5566544   Other Benefit     12000.0   18000.0
> Annex  5014255   Salary            66667.2  155556.8
> Annex  5324232   Taxes             15000.6   35001.4
> Annex  5566544   Other Benefit      9001.2   21002.8
> ```

This of course is just a basic example. The real file has several more validations and several categories of weights that are used for different accounts. In order to pull the information I have the following formula.

```
    =IFNA(SUMPRODUCT(
   INDIRECT(INDEX("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(6,COLUMN($A$5)+MATCH($N5,Sheet1!$1:$1,0)-1,4)&":"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN($A$5)+MATCH($N5,Sheet1!$1:$1,0)-1,4),"1","")&$AU$1,1,1)),
    --(Sheet1!$C$6:$C$1754=2018),
    --(Sheet1!$J$6:$J$1754=$I5),
    IF($G5=1,Sheet1!$BN$6:$BN$1754,IF($F5=1,Sheet1!$BA$6:$BA$1754,Sheet1!$AN$6:$AN$1754))
    ),0)
```

The important piece of code is:

```
INDIRECT(INDEX("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(6,COLUMN($A$5)+MATCH($N5,Sheet1!$1:$1,0)-1,4)&":"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN($A$5)+MATCH($N5,Sheet1!$1:$1,0)-1,4),"1","")&$AU$1,1,1))
```

This uses string manipulation to generate the column range according to the account number. So for example, the account number `5014255` would generate `Sheet1!$C$6:$C$1754`, so that the values in that column can be gathered according to weight and validations.

So, I'm trying to change the logic to remove volatiles. But so far I haven't been able to do it.

I basically need my summary to find the column where the account number is, so it can do the sumproduct calculations with that column.

Any ideas or suggestions on how to work around this?

Answer (score 0):

To get the full column without volatiles use:

```
INDEX(Sheet1!$C$6:$E$1754,0,MATCH($N5,Sheet1!$C$1:$E$1,0))
```

This will return the correct column to the SUMPRODUCT formula